# Modify metadata as if the file is copied from another file

Tags: svn

If I create b.config by svn copy, when I commit the file, histroy will say it's copied from another file, as the figure shows.

[image]

Now I have c.config that I manually created in Explorer. I don't want to delete it and recreate using svn copy.

Is there a svn command that I can link c.config to web.config, as if c.config is "svn copy"-ed from web.config?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for **Repair Copy**. Open commit window, show unversioned file, select the two files you want to link, right-click and choose Repair Copy.

See https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-commit.htm for more details (search for **Repairing External Copies**). Similary, you can **Repair Move**.

It's still not clean how to do that in command line.